# How to activate Net Reactor License in Azure DevOps pipeline with cloud hosted virtual machines?

Tags: .net, azure-pipelines, obfuscation, net-reactor

I purchased Net Reactor 6.9 from Eziriz because they advertise that they have Azure DevOps pipeline integration (https://www.eziriz.com/reactor_features.htm):
[Net Reactor Azure DevOps Integration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8EW5.png)

It worked in my pipeline and obfuscated my assemblies correctly.

The problem is that the license file they send in email only works with a single machine based in it's hardware identification.

I read in the discussion of their Azure DevOps Extension page (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Eziriz.reactor-tool-task) that we should ask their support to send a special license file for this use:
[Discussion in Q&A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPsJV.png)

I've sent several emails to their support for this and never got a response.

Does anybody accomplished to receive this special license and/or activated Net Reactor successfully in pipelines?

I tried adding the license file itself and the base64 content in my pipeline, but both failed the same way.

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-2019'
```

```
- task: DotNetReactorTool@0
  displayName: Activating NetReactor (obfuscator)
  inputs:
    version: '6.9.0.0'
    license: 'hMXw6GpxGVj87v6RLKLYmm7kMOs6rN...'
    #license: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Setup/NetReactor/license.license'
```

There is no error showed in the pipeline log regarding the activation, but Net Reactor obfuscate with the demo version and after 14 days your software starts showing for each assembly a message box with "Net Reactor Demo Version".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "special license" they sent me worked as expected. My obfuscated assemblies still works ok after the trial period.

So to anyone trying to use Net Reactor in Azure DevOps Pipelines with cloud hosted agents, it'll not work unless their support respond to you.

In my case it took at least 4 months until they answer me.